# python run bash command get bad result

Tags: python, bash, cmd

Hi I'm trying to run this bash cmd on python 3.2. Here is the python code:

```
message = '\\x61'
shell_command = "echo -n -e '" + message + "' | md5"
print(shell_command)
event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(event.communicate())
```

this gave me next result:
**echo -n -e '\x61' | md5

(b'713b2a82dc713ef273502c00787f9417\n', None)**
But when I run this printed cmd in bash, I get different result:
**0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661**

Where I did mistake?

Comment: Curious, it works for me in python 2.5 (that is, returns 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661)

Comment: But if what you really wnat is the MD5 hash, just use the hashlib module (and its md5 function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this problem is when you say:

> But when I run this printed cmd in bash...

The `Popen` function of the subprocess module does not necessarily use bash, it may use some other shell such as `/bin/sh` which will not necessarily handle the `echo` command identically to bash. On my system running the command in bash produces the same result as you get:

```
$ echo -n -e '\x61' | md5sum
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -
```

But if I run the command in `/bin/sh` I get:

```
$ echo -n -e '\x61' | md5sum
20b5b5ca564e98e1fadc00ebdc82ed63  -
```

This is because `/bin/sh` on my system doesn't understand the `-e` option nor does it understand the `\x` escape sequence.

If I run your code in python I get the same result as if I'd used `/bin/sh`:

```
>>> cmd = "echo -n -e '\\x61' | md5sum"
>>> event = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> print event.communicate()
('20b5b5ca564e98e1fadc00ebdc82ed63  -\n', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use echo to pass data. You can do it directly with python, i.e.:

```
Popen('/usr/bin/md5sum', shell=False, stdin=PIPE).communicate('\x61')
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> `communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`.

That matches up with the tuple you got back:

```
(b'713b2a82dc713ef273502c00787f9417\n', None)
```

To access just the standard output (`stdoutdata`), you want element `0` of that tuple:

```
print(event.communicate()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
>>> p=Popen('echo -n \x61 |md5sum',shell=True,stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
(b'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -\n', None)
```